# Cannot manually download updates from download.microsoft.com using three different browsers

Tags: windows-7, firefox, internet-explorer, download, windows-10-preview

So, I have both windows 7 and windows 10 installed on two computers. (Total of four operating systems) And I need to download [User-Mode Driver Framework version 1.11 update for Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38421), but when I click 'Click here' and select x64 version, and click download, the popup box goes away (as per usual) and nothing happens. On all four operating systems. Tried multiple times, tried waiting in excess of 30 minutes.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't expect to get a response, but if anyone has the same problem, it's adblock or built in saftey measures in chrome. On the top right you have to click 'Load unsafe scripts'

Comment: confirmed, I had to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

On the last page,

`If your download does not start after 30 seconds, Click here`

After seeing above line, click the `click here` link, this will bring you back to the file selection page, except the download link now become available and clickable. Click this link to get the files.

Here is the direct link for the files

http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/E/91E874B3-AFCF-405E-981C-22E183516C49/Umdf-1.11-Win-6.1-x86.msu

http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/E/91E874B3-AFCF-405E-981C-22E183516C49/Umdf-1.11-Win-6.1-x64.msu

Original file selection page
[image: 1]

After going back to the same old page, download link available now
[image: 2]